# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSectionNames() after upgrading to 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.4

We've faced this issue when we've upgraded Magento Commerce `2.3.2 to 2.3.4`.

Error was like:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   getSectionNames() on
>   /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/js/section-config.phtml:20

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We found the solution here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26647

We've overridden the vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml in our custom theme. 
So, changing its structure during the upgrade caused the issue. Ours was missing the **"sectionNamesProvider"** argument tag for **customer.section.config** block.

```
<block name="customer.section.config" class="Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig"
               template="Magento_Customer::js/section-config.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="sectionNamesProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\SectionNamesProvider</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

We couldn't predict this. As Magento guys said, this is an issue that needs to be solved.

*"Stuff like this happens very frequently in "patch" releases. We should somehow try to avoid this."*