# Magento 2.3x Multi-Vendor Marketplace, The Vendor Panel is showing a blank white page

Tags: magento2, marketplace, multi-vendor, magento2marketplace

I had upgraded the PHP version from 7.1 to 7.2 and also the Magento2 version from 2.2 to 2.3.6 community version, since then the Vendor panel is not loading and is just showing a blank page. If I disable the separate dashboard, the panel loads in the customer account.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Customer/js/section-config": {
                "sections": {"stores\/store\/switch":["*"],"stores\/store\/switchrequest":["*"],"directory\/currency\/switch":["*"],"*":["messages"],"customer\/account\/logout":["*","recently_viewed_product","recently_compared_product","persistent"],"customer\/account\/loginpost":["*"],"customer\/account\/createpost":["*"],"customer\/account\/editpost":["*"],"customer\/ajax\/login":["checkout-data","cart","captcha"],"catalog\/product_compare\/add":["compare-products"],"catalog\/product_compare\/remove":["compare-products"],"catalog\/product_compare\/clear":["compare-products"],"sales\/guest\/reorder":["cart"],"sales\/order\/reorder":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/add":["cart","directory-data"],"checkout\/cart\/delete":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/updatepost":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/updateitemoptions":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/couponpost":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/estimatepost":["cart"],"checkout\/cart\/estimateupdatepost":["cart"],"checkout\/onepage\/saveorder":["cart","checkout-data","last-ordered-items"],"checkout\/sidebar\/removeitem":["cart"],"checkout\/sidebar\/updateitemqty":["cart"],"rest\/*\/v1\/carts\/*\/payment-information":["cart","last-ordered-items","instant-purchase"],"rest\/*\/v1\/guest-carts\/*\/payment-information":["cart"],"rest\/*\/v1\/guest-carts\/*\/selected-payment-method":["cart","checkout-data"],"rest\/*\/v1\/carts\/*\/selected-payment-method":["cart","checkout-data","instant-purchase"],"customer\/address\/*":["instant-purchase"],"customer\/account\/*":["instant-purchase"],"vault\/cards\/deleteaction":["instant-purchase"],"multishipping\/checkout\/overviewpost":["cart"],"authorizenet\/directpost_payment\/place":["cart","checkout-data"],"paypal\/express\/placeorder":["cart","checkout-data"],"paypal\/payflowexpress\/placeorder":["cart","checkout-data"],"paypal\/express\/onauthorization":["cart","checkout-data"],"persistent\/index\/unsetcookie":["persistent"],"review\/product\/post":["review"],"braintree\/paypal\/placeorder":["cart","checkout-data"],"wishlist\/index\/add":["wishlist"],"wishlist\/index\/remove":["wishlist"],"wishlist\/index\/updateitemoptions":["wishlist"],"wishlist\/index\/update":["wishlist"],"wishlist\/index\/cart":["wishlist","cart"],"wishlist\/index\/fromcart":["wishlist","cart"],"wishlist\/index\/allcart":["wishlist","cart"],"wishlist\/shared\/allcart":["wishlist","cart"],"wishlist\/shared\/cart":["cart"],"ajaxcartpro\/cart\/add":["cart"],"sociallogin\/popup\/create":["checkout-data","cart"]},
                "clientSideSections": ["checkout-data","cart-data","chatData"],
                "baseUrls": ["https:\/\/www.empohub.com\/"],
                "sectionNames": <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSectionNames() on null in /home4/empohwgo/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/js/section-config.phtml:20
Stack trace:
#0 /home4/empohwgo/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include()
#1 /home4/empohwgo/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php-&gt;render(Object(Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig), '/home4/empohwgo...', Array)
#2 /home4/empohwgo/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor-&gt;___callParent('render', Array)
#3 /home4/empohwgo/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor-&gt;Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Customer\Block\SectionConfig), '/home4/empohwgo...', Array)
#4 /home4/empohwgo/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Template in <b>/home4/empohwgo/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/js/section-config.phtml</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
```

Comment: which multi vendor marketplace extension you are using?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303041/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-getsectionnames-after-u check this one.

Comment: I am using Magento2 Webkul Multi vendor marketplace